# Multi-part Join Form

Tags: wordpress, profile

I want to collect a lot of information from members, but I don't want it to have 30 fields on the same page, it'll be too intimidating.  I want to break it up across multiple pages.  "Join - Page 1 of 3"  etc

How do I do that?

I know how to link one form to another, so that upon completing a form the user is directed to the next form.  But how do I get CiviCRM to recognize that they are the same person?  So the entered information goes to the same record?

I don't want them to have to create a login on the site.  I'm using Wordpress.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you try out Caldera Forms CiviCRM WordPress plugin: https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm

You need to firstly install the Caldera Forms plug-in for WordPress and then install the Caldera Forms CiviCRM plug-in (also for WordPress). Caldera Forms out of the box, allows for the creation of multiple pages for a single form. The Caldera Forms CiviCRM plug-in, adds the integration with Caldera Forms and CiviCRM. I currently have both plug-ins installed in our WordPress site and I'm busy exploring the creating of a contact capture form with custom CiviCRM fields. The form is pretty large, so I am busy splitting it into multiple pages. I have not tested any form submission yet, but hope to complete the form and test it within the next week.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution would be to create a single-page form but use Javascript to format the fields like a Wizard.

Comment: How would that look/work?

Comment: http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at gravity forms. You can do mulitpage. https://www.gravityforms.com/

There is also a CiviCRM/Gravity Forms Integration Extension http://shop.civivip.com/civi-plugins/gravity-forms-integration/ I have not used the integration so I cannot answer for sure that it will record all the answers in their contact profile.

I use it on our site and love it. https://radiusinternational.org/student-application/

I have also tested Caldera Forms about 6 months ago then went with Gravity. I highly recommend Gravity Forms.

Comment: If you don't have the integration now, how do you get the information from Gravity Forms into CiviCRM?

Comment: So we'd have to pay $59 a year for gravity forms and then another $89 a year for the integration?  That seems pricey for us.